# What are the different concepts of Maya available in different scriptures and different sects?

Tags: terminology, maya

What are the different concepts of Maya available in different scriptures and different sects? Please mention the uniqueness of each concept clearly.

Comment: question looks too broad

Comment: @Pandya i want just definitions

Answer (score 2):

The term [māyā](https://encyclopediaofbuddhism.org/wiki/Maya_(illusion)) occurs 70 times in Rigveda and around 27 times in the Atharvaveda; and in all these places Yaska, Sayana, Dayananda Saraswati agree the term means **Prajñā**, **jnana-vishesha** (specific knowledge). The term Asuri-Maya in the Yajurveda at one place was translated by Uvvat as the "knowledge of the vital air". With regard to the usage of the word Maya in the Rigveda, Radhakrishnan opines it was only used to signify **might and power**. Maya as the cause of **illusion** or as the sense of **Avidya** (lack of knowledge) has never been used in the Vedas.

yAska in his nighantu, which is a etymological explanation of vedas, derives "**prajnA**" or consciousness as the meaning of the word **mAyA**. ( nighantu kAnda of [nirukta](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZMkbWhjE2M4C&pg=PA661&lpg=PA661&dq=maya%20yaska%20prajna&source=bl&ots=gloQYzD9ma&sig=ACfU3U0et7ZPcen67hrR4m3gbLVnRdmEfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXnpH6_NTgAhUG1qwKHVfNAicQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=maya%20yaska%20prajna&f=false) 3.9)

Comment: Thanks.I hv upvoted,Let me wait for some more answers:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reference to ALL but I can certainly contribute a very simple, precise and interesting definition of Maya.

According to Bhagwan Swaminarayan,

> Maya is anything that obstructs a devotee of God while meditating on the God's form."
>
> -[**Vachanamrut** Gadhada Chapter I - 1](https://www.anirdesh.com/vachanamrut/index.php?format=en&vachno=1)

[Original](https://download.baps.org/Data/Sites/1/Media/DownloadableFile/Books/Vachanamrut.pdf)
[English Translation](https://www.anirdesh.com/vachanamrut/index.php?format=en&vachno=1)

Answer (score -1):

you should watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzY2D_KAc44

This topic is very broad, on one view, maya effects the mind, and externally its "time, space and energy"

According to Bhagwat mahapuran, what you are referring to is  Mahamaya.

Mahamaya is the external energy of Krishna. Like a framework through which He executes and maintains the creation.

Another is Yogmaya. research on it.

Comment: i am afraid youtube is not a dependable reference.

Comment: YouTube and Movies are not authentic sources.  Refer [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! "Another is Yogmaya. research on it." this looks like a comment not an answer. Visit [answer]. You should cite some sources and add explanation.